# How to initialize start index of scrollView paging?

Tags: swift, uiscrollview

I've a `UIScrollView` that contains an array of `UIImageView`. The `UIScrollView` has paging enabled. What I want is that I can set the initial index, so it will start at index 3 instead of index 0. Is that possible?

Comment: What about using a collectionView instead?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
func scrollToImageAt(index: Int) {
    let imageView = imageViews[index]
    let yOffset = imageView.frame.origin.y
    scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: yOffset), animated: true)
}
```

Comment: I came to this. But can't get it work: `scrollView.scrollRectToVisible`